# Pop up Message display in android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-toast

I have an app running on google play. I want to notify my app users with an alter/notification message over a period of 2 weeks of time. It should notify every time when they open the app. So to do this, i guess the answer is using "Dialogue box".

In practicality, when i code dialogue box with different messages, then i need update my apk file everytime i change the alter messages. So, do i need to update my apk file over the google play every time when i update with different alter messages?

Comment: basically yes it seems the reasonable solution, or you can use some server and get the messages from there every time.

Comment: Definitely you will have to update your apk file everytime on google play store when you put a minor change too.

Comment: ok, its seems bit of work, i thought there would be some easy way to sent the alter messages. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

as @meh said its not possible to send a pop up message without uploading a new apk or some server does this for us.

I have seen a beautiful website that can act as a webserve and push the notification as a dialogue and also as a notification.

[Look this link here](https://www.parse.com/)

Which might here for some one who have same question like me.